# "Moksha" and Arms and Weapons

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, mantras, other-religions, gayatri-mantra

> Is the attainment of moksha the final stage of Hinduism? after achieving the goal they again take arms and weapons in their hands?>> because working is better than remaining idle. Those who thought attainment  Moksha has brought to the ultimate aim, form political parties, terrorist organizations, etc. What for? >>>>can any person become free only for the sake of peace? my question is CAN Wars and peace efforts, which are transient, transitory bring an end to this cycle{circle} there is no end to this cycle of rotation. but Don't we believe in taking part in Prayers and worships at the same time, that occupy major parts of our lives

Comment: Your question is not very clear. There are many questions actually. Kindly ask the main question separately. Also formatting is wrong. The block quote is not necessary as I suppose all the texts are your own.

Comment: @Rickross-There is no site for astrology in the stack exchange network. But the evolution of Hinduism. And the up-to-date reference to astronomy is essential just like ROBOTS/ROBOTICS FOR UTTERING ONE WORD AND HISTORY OF HINDUISM TILL DATE CAN'T OMIT ROBOTS/ROBOTICS. AND ENGLISH.I APOLOGIZE.USER-37920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hare Krishna,

I try answer everything from Bhagavad Gita.

Before answering, first let see in general what Gita say about us, soul:

> The living entities in this conditioned world are My eternal, fragmental parts. *Source:* https://asitis.com/15/7.html

And about abode of God and spirirtual world.

> There are two classes of beings, the fallible and the infallible. In the material world every entity is fallible, **and in the spiritual world every entity is called infallible**. *Source:* https://asitis.com/15/16.html

> That abode of Mine is not illumined by the sun or moon, nor by electricity. One who reaches it never returns to this material world. *Source:* https://asitis.com/15/6.html

Now let's see what could be say:

> Is the attainment of moksha the final stage of Hinduism?

According to Gita, as there is spiritual world, and as we are part and parcel of God, so to serve God is final Goal.

> after achieving the goal they again take arms and weapons in their hands?

It may depends on many aspects. As spiritual world is inconceivable by most of us, we can't think what exactly will be there, but can take equivalent to weapons for service in God if needed.

> because working is better than remaining idle. Those who thought attainment  Moksha has brought to the ultimate aim, form political parties, terrorist organizations, etc. What for?

Moksha and spiritual world is based on authentic scriptures, which has received to us to by Acharya, who has preserved meaning and message of it, and can confirm any time by realising it. It isn't to form any political party or organisation, but to let us know what really our relationship with God, and why we are suffering in material world, by mercy of Lord.

And as per Acharya, at ultimate devotion in spiritual world, it isn't idle, but to to be in unlimited bliss by serving Krishna.

> can any person become free only for the sake of peace?

Person become free from material world, and can enter into spiritual world by mercy of spiritual master, and God as per Acharya.

But mercy of God is available to those who try for devotional service, and as per wish of God. So if one for sake of peace do something unrelated to God, he will get results of action or Karma as per action. But what needed to attain spiritual world or Vaikuntha or Goloka, is mainly devotional service and mercy of Supreme Lord.

> my question is CAN Wars and peace efforts, which are transient, transitory bring an end to this cycle{circle} there is no end to this cycle of rotation. but Don't we believe in taking part in Prayers and worships at the same time, that occupy major parts of our lives

War and Peace is related to material world, and untill someone doesn't want to return in spiritual world, and doesn't involve in devotional service, it will affect as per law of karma. After in devotional service, if one becomes pure devotee, everything happens as per wish of Lord as devotee has surrender to Supreme Lord.

And transition of birth and death can stopped if one is in service of Supreme Lord.

Comment: can moksha be attained without the help of ROBOTS[robotics]? every country has its own satellites and also in the context of astronomy[ASTROLOGY HAS NO SITE IN STACK EXCHANGE NETWORK]. SO ROBOTICS, ROBOTS ARE INDISPENSABLE FOR ATTAINING  'MOKSHA". user-37920